How to access Artifact from Azure Extension?
I am currently trying to access a pusblished artifact from my Azure Extension.
Unfortunately, I don't get a response, not even an error is displayed.
I think there is a problem with the client.
The permissions are set correctly I think since I was eg able to retrive the project name and ID.


import * as SDK from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";
import { getClient } from "azure-devops-extension-api";
import { BuildRestClient } from "azure-devops-extension-api/Build";
import { Page } from "azure-devops-ui/Page";
import { ZeroData } from "azure-devops-ui/ZeroData";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Tab extends React.Component<{}, { artifactContext?: string, debugInfo?: string }> {
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { artifactContext: undefined, debugInfo: undefined };
    }

    public async componentDidMount() {
        await SDK.init();
        const projectName = "Project Name";
        const buildId = xxx;
        const artifactName = "artifact_name";

        try {
            const buildClient = await getClient(BuildRestClient);
            const artifact = await buildClient.getArtifact(projectName, buildId, artifactName);
            if (artifact) {
                this.setState({
                    artifactContext: JSON.stringify(artifact, null, 2),
                    debugInfo: "Artifact was successfully retrieved."
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    artifactContext: "No artifact was returned.",
                    debugInfo: "No artifact found with the specified name."
                });
            }
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.error("Error fetching artifact:", error);
            this.setState({
                artifactContext: `Error fetching artifact: ${error.message}`,
                debugInfo: `API call failed: ${error.message}`
            });
        }
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        const { artifactContext, debugInfo } = this.state;

        return (
            <Page className="flex-grow">
                <ZeroData
                    primaryText="Fetching artifact..."
                    secondaryText={"Please wait while the artifact is being fetched."}
                    imageAltText="Fetching data"
                />
                {artifactContext && (
                    <div>
                        <h3>Artifact Context:</h3>
                        <pre>{artifactContext}</pre>
                    </div>
                )}
                {debugInfo && (
                    <div>
                        <h3>Debug Information:</h3>
                        <pre>{debugInfo}</pre>
                    </div>
                )}
            </Page>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Tab />, document.getElementById("root"));



What could I do diffrently or try out to fix my problem?
Thank you

Did you encounter this problem when using the extension or debugging the above code? Can you share more debug details or issue page of the relevant issue?

I have installed the extension to try it out. I have put in more print statements to debug and the SDK.init and also getClient seem to work but it doesn't get passed the getArtifact. Could permission be an issue? The SDK handles authnetication so there wouldn't be a need for eg a PAT right?

so "Artifact was successfully retrieved." is not displayed

I get the follwoing error message: "The AzureDevOps SDK is already loaded. Only one version of this module can be loaded in a given document."

For the error message, you can refer to this ticket: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-api/issues/109 The cause of the issue is the 'azure-devops-extension-sdk' and 'azure-devops-extension-api' are using different way for dependency.

Thank you so much! I have downgraded the sdk to the same version that the azure-devops-extension-api is using as dependency and now it works

Glad to know that it can work for you now. You can add a answer to share the solution. This will be helpful to other users who have the same issue.

Thanks, Kevin Lu-MSFT for your positive input, which was instrumental in resolving  mr_bean's problem. Posting the same as a solution for anyone else on Stack overflow community encountering a similar issue
Problem:
The SDK initialization and getClient worked, but getArtifact did not proceed. Error message indicated that multiple versions of the AzureDevOps SDK were loaded: "The AzureDevOps SDK is already loaded. Only one version of this module can be loaded in a given document."
Fix:
The versions of azure-devops-extension-sdk and azure-devops-extension-api should be aligned to avoid conflicts.
npm list azure-devops-extension-sdk
npm list azure-devops-extension-api

Downgrade or upgrade accordingly as per your environment state the azure-devops-extension-sdk to match the version used by the azure-devops-extension-api.
Therefore, for mr_bean's issue, it was due to version mismatches between the azure-devops-extension-sdk and azure-devops-extension-api. By downgrading the SDK to the same version that the azure-devops-extension-api is using, the issue was resolved. Kevin Lu-MSFT and mr_bean, feel free to edit the answer to add anything I missed here.
